# I have an image gallery and i want to open each image using modal when click on each

Tags: javascript, html, css

I build an image gallery with 13 photos that i found in w3school and I rebuilt for my own needs, the gallery looks nice, but the thing is that I can open only the first image using modal and I edited
a of javascript  code snippe that I also found in w3schools, but works just for the first one image not for the rest, I'm novice working with javascript and I want to improve this opening each image of the gallery using modal when I touch or click each image.
This is the code what i'm using.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById("image-gall-1");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption-gallery-fu-sc");
img.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close-gallery-fu-sc")[0];
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE 10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE 10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Create two equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
  -ms-flex: 50%; /* IE 10 */
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 60px 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#image-gall-1,#image-gall-2,#image-gall-3,#image-gall-4,#image-gall-5,#image-gall-6,#image-gall-7,#image-gall-8,#image-gall-9,#image-gall-10,#image-gall-11,#image-gall-12,#image-gall-13 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
#image-gall-1:hover, #image-gall-2:hover, #image-gall-3:hover, #image-gall-4:hover, #image-gall-5:hover,#image-gall-6:hover, #image-gall-7:hover, #image-gall-8:hover, #image-gall-9:hover, #image-gall-10:hover, #image-gall-11:hover, #image-gall-12:hover, #image-gall-13:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal-gallery-fu-sc {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content-gallery-fu-sc {
  padding-top:80px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}
/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption-gallery-fu-sc {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}
/* Add Animation */
.modal-content-gallery-fu-sc, #caption-gallery-fu-sc {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}
@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}
/* The Close Button */
.close-gallery-fu-sc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 85px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.close-gallery-fu-sc:hover,
.close-gallery-fu-sc:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content-gallery-fu-sc {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal-gallery-fu-sc">
  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close-gallery-fu-sc">×</span>
  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content-gallery-fu-sc" id="img01">
  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption-gallery-fu-sc"></div>
</div>

<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="column">
    <img id="image-gall-1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" alt="wedding" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-2" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" alt="rocks" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-3" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/falls2.jpg" alt="falls2" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-4" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" alt="paris" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-5" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/nature.jpg" alt="nature" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-6" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mist.jpg" alt="mist" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-7" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" alt="paris" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img id="image-gall-8" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" alt="underwater" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-9" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/ocean.jpg" alt="ocean" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-10" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" alt="wedding" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-11" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mountainskies.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-12" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" alt="rocks" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-13" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" alt="underwater" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target each `img` in your gallery, not just from one specific `id`.

```
var img = document.querySelectorAll(".column img");
```

And loop over those images:

```
img.forEach((imgA)=>{
    imgA.onclick = function(){
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = this.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
});
```

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.querySelectorAll(".column img");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption-gallery-fu-sc");

img.forEach((imgA)=>{
    imgA.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
});

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close-gallery-fu-sc")[0];
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE 10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE 10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Create two equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
  -ms-flex: 50%; /* IE 10 */
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 60px 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#image-gall-1,#image-gall-2,#image-gall-3,#image-gall-4,#image-gall-5,#image-gall-6,#image-gall-7,#image-gall-8,#image-gall-9,#image-gall-10,#image-gall-11,#image-gall-12,#image-gall-13 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
#image-gall-1:hover, #image-gall-2:hover, #image-gall-3:hover, #image-gall-4:hover, #image-gall-5:hover,#image-gall-6:hover, #image-gall-7:hover, #image-gall-8:hover, #image-gall-9:hover, #image-gall-10:hover, #image-gall-11:hover, #image-gall-12:hover, #image-gall-13:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal-gallery-fu-sc {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content-gallery-fu-sc {
  padding-top:80px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}
/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption-gallery-fu-sc {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}
/* Add Animation */
.modal-content-gallery-fu-sc, #caption-gallery-fu-sc {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}
@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}
/* The Close Button */
.close-gallery-fu-sc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 85px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.close-gallery-fu-sc:hover,
.close-gallery-fu-sc:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content-gallery-fu-sc {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal-gallery-fu-sc">
  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close-gallery-fu-sc">×</span>
  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content-gallery-fu-sc" id="img01">
  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption-gallery-fu-sc"></div>
</div>

<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="column">
    <img id="image-gall-1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" alt="wedding" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-2" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" alt="rocks" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-3" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/falls2.jpg" alt="falls2" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-4" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" alt="paris" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-5" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/nature.jpg" alt="nature" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-6" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mist.jpg" alt="mist" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-7" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" alt="paris" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img id="image-gall-8" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" alt="underwater" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-9" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/ocean.jpg" alt="ocean" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-10" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" alt="wedding" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-11" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mountainskies.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-12" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" alt="rocks" style="width:100%">
    <img id="image-gall-13" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" alt="underwater" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Work great! I want to add that my site is build in Wordpress with my own template. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You have only added a click event listener to the first image. That's why the modal is not opened when other images are clicked. To solve it, you can add event listeners to other images following the code of the first image. But, it would be a lot of code with small changes. So, you can add a class to every image, select the elements using the class name and add event listerens using a loop.

```
var images = document.getElementById("image-gall");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption-gallery-fu-sc");    
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
    var img = images[i];
    img.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
}
```

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("image-gall");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption-gallery-fu-sc");    
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
    var img = images[i];
    img.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
}
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close-gallery-fu-sc")[0];
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE 10 */
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE 10 */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Create two equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
    -ms-flex: 50%; /* IE 10 */
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 60px 4px;
}

.column img {
    margin-top: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#image-gall-1,#image-gall-2,#image-gall-3,#image-gall-4,#image-gall-5,#image-gall-6,#image-gall-7,#image-gall-8,#image-gall-9,#image-gall-10,#image-gall-11,#image-gall-12,#image-gall-13 {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
#image-gall-1:hover, #image-gall-2:hover, #image-gall-3:hover, #image-gall-4:hover, #image-gall-5:hover,#image-gall-6:hover, #image-gall-7:hover, #image-gall-8:hover, #image-gall-9:hover, #image-gall-10:hover, #image-gall-11:hover, #image-gall-12:hover, #image-gall-13:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal-gallery-fu-sc {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content-gallery-fu-sc {
    padding-top:80px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}
/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption-gallery-fu-sc {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}
/* Add Animation */
.modal-content-gallery-fu-sc, #caption-gallery-fu-sc {  
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}
@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}
/* The Close Button */
.close-gallery-fu-sc {
    position: absolute;
    top: 85px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.close-gallery-fu-sc:hover,
.close-gallery-fu-sc:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content-gallery-fu-sc {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal-gallery-fu-sc">
        <!-- The Close Button -->
        <span class="close-gallery-fu-sc">×</span>
        <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
        <img class="modal-content-gallery-fu-sc" id="img01">
        <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
        <div id="caption-gallery-fu-sc"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Photo Grid -->
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="column">
            <img id="image-gall-1" class="image-gall" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" alt="wedding" style="width:100%">
            <img id="image-gall-2" class="image-gall" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" alt="rocks" style="width:100%">
            <img id="image-gall-3" class="image-gall" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/falls2.jpg" alt="falls2" style="width:100%">
            <img id="image-gall-4" class="image-gall" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" alt="paris" style="width:100%">
            <img id="image-gall-5" class="image-gall" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/nature.jpg" alt="nature" style="width:100%">
            <img id="image-gall-6" class="image-gall" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mist.jpg" alt="mist" style="width:100%">
            <img id="image-gall-7" class="image-gall" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" alt="paris" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img id="image-gall-8" class="image-gall" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" alt="underwater" style="width:100%">
            <img id="image-gall-9" class="image-gall" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/ocean.jpg" alt="ocean" style="width:100%">
            <img id="image-gall-10" class="image-gall" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" alt="wedding" style="width:100%">
            <img id="image-gall-11" class="image-gall" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mountainskies.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
            <img id="image-gall-12" class="image-gall" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" alt="rocks" style="width:100%">
            <img id="image-gall-13" class="image-gall" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" alt="underwater" style="width:100%">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi... I see when i run your code snippet, works fine here in the platform, but when I run it in my site doesn't work, I don't understand why that happen. I have a wordpress site, with my own template, and no external plugins.